# Is their any way for transcribe an large audio file by python and librosa?

Tags: python, librosa, wit.ai, transcription, amazon-transcribe

I am trying to do by so many platform.
Firstly i tried with speech recognition module but this is not working.
Secondly i tried with wit.ai but it can't process large file.
At lastly i tried with aws transcribe but I have a student account so I can't connect with python..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please ask a specific coding question here. I suggest you ask questions about one of the problems you encountered in your failed approaches.